# Apache Camel 2.14 Rest DSL Security

Tags: security, rest, apache-camel

I would like to use the new Rest DSL in Apache Camel 2.14 to create a rest interface. I would like to use the Jetty component and I have a basic example setup like this:

**Spring Security Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:spring-security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring-security http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring-security/camel-spring-security.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


<spring-security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    <spring-security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    <spring-security:http-basic></spring-security:http-basic>
</spring-security:http>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="true"/>
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<spring-security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <spring-security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
</spring-security:authentication-manager>


<spring-security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
    <spring-security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <spring-security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
</spring-security:user-service>


<authorizationPolicy id="admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN"
                     authenticationManager="authenticationManager"
                     accessDecisionManager="accessDecisionManager"
                     xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring-security"/>

<authorizationPolicy id="user" access="ROLE_USER"
                     xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring-security"/>
```

**Camel Route Configuration**

```
restConfiguration().component("jetty").host("0.0.0.0").port(24999).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");

    rest("address").description("Contains services for addresses").
            consumes("application/json").
            produces("application/json").
            get().      
            route().policy("admin").
            to("bean:restAddressApi?method=queryAddress").endRest();
```

When I try to access this protected URL using wget with this:

```
 wget --http-user=admin --http-password=admin http://localhost:24999/address/
```

Then I get this error in the console:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelAuthorizationException: Cannot find the Authentication instance.. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]
at org.apache.camel.component.spring.security.SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy.beforeProcess(SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.component.spring.security.SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy$AuthorizeDelegateProcess.process(SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy.java:120)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.service(CamelContinuationServlet.java:150)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler.handle(ResourceHandler.java:406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I missing in my config to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved it using Apache Camel 2.15.2. I use this backend together with an AngularJS frontent where I use an httpInterceptor to add the authenitcation header.
I use JWT to store a tenantId in the authorization header. This tenantId is used together with Hibernate and its Multi Tenancy Support.

Front end login controller, using AngularJs and written in TypeScript:

```
 /// <reference path="../reference.ts"/>
module Controllers {

  export class Credentials {
    username:string;
    password:string;
  }

  export interface ILoginControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
    credentials:Credentials;
    login:()=>void;
  }

  export class LoginController {
    private _scope:ILoginControllerScope;

    static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'UserService', '$location'];

    constructor($scope:ILoginControllerScope, $http:ng.IHttpService, UserService:UserService, $location:ng.ILocationService) {
      this._scope = $scope;
      $scope.credentials = new Credentials();

      $scope.login = ()=> {
        $http.post('/api/authenticate', $scope.credentials)
          .success(function (data:string, status:any, headers:any, config:any) {
            // Remove all " characters from string.
            data = data.replace(/"/gi, '');
            UserService.setSecurityToken(data);
            $location.path('/');
          })
          .error(function (data:any, status:any, headers:any, config:any) {

          });
      }
    }
  }
}



 @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> credentials = exchange.getIn().getBody(HashMap.class);
    String username = credentials.get("username");
    String password = credentials.get("password");

        // Login logic that returns object() containing user info
        exchange.getIn().setBody(jwtService.generateToken(tenantConfiguration));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class JwtService that is responsible for creating a JWT Token:

```
package com.me.services;

import com.me.TenantConfiguration;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

@Service
public class JwtService {

    public static final String TENANT_ID = "tenant_id";
    public static final String ROLE = "role";

    @Value("${jwt.subject}")
    private String jwtSubject;

    private byte[] signingKey;

    private SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

    public SignatureAlgorithm getSignatureAlgorithm() {
        return signatureAlgorithm;
    }

    public byte[] getSigningKey() {
        if (this.signingKey == null) {
            // Generate new signingKey
            Random random = new SecureRandom();
            signingKey = new byte[64];
            random.nextBytes(signingKey);
        }
        return this.signingKey;
    }

    public String getJwtSubject() {
        return jwtSubject;
    }

    public String generateToken(TenantConfiguration tenantConfiguration){
        Map<String, Object> claims = Maps.newHashMap();
        claims.put(TENANT_ID, tenantConfiguration.getSessionId());
        String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(this.getJwtSubject()).setClaims(claims).signWith(this.getSignatureAlgorithm(), this.getSigningKey()).compact();
        return token;
    }
}
```

To use this in a route I define it like this:

```
        rest("api/messages").description("Restful API for messages").
            get().id("GetMessages").route().to("springSecurityContextLoader").policy(authorizationPolicy).to("bean:restMessageApi?method=getAllMessages").endRest().
```

SpringSecurityContextloader

```
@Service
public class SpringSecurityContextLoader implements Processor {
@Inject
private JwtService jwtService;

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    String authorization = exchange.getIn().getHeader("Authorization", String.class);

    Jwt jwt = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtService.getSigningKey()).parse(authorization);

    Map<String, Object> claims = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getBody();
    String tenantId = claims.get(JwtService.TENANT_ID).toString();

    Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(tenantId, "something", Lists.newArrayList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

Comment: A new user tried to reply to this answer by suggesting an edit. I'm copying the text here: `Please add the missing authorizationPolicy definition and correctly end the rest() route, which is incomplete, that way is more uderstandable. (Where does authorizationPolicy comes from? where was it defined?, also, after endRest() is there something missing? it ends with . )`

Comment: @P3anuts seem to be a good work, but incomplete, please review it.

Comment: Do you have a link to source files?

Answer (score 3):

Two options.

1. You can use basic auth with jetty rest DSL.  I just spent some time working with basic auth, a jetty rest DSL service, and camel 2.15.  I wrote up my experiences here: http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/2065 . I found the camel-jetty wiki page a bit out of date, full code here: https://github.com/mooreds/camel-rest-jetty-auth
2. You can use spring security (at least with version 2.15.2 of camel and 4.0.1.RELEASE of spring security, which is what I am using). To do so, you need to make sure you create a processor class, as outlined here: http://camel.apache.org/spring-security.html#SpringSecurity-Authentication and put it in front of every route before you call the `policy`.  You also need to create an exception handler to present a nice message to an unauthorized user--here's what I did in my java routebuilder: `onException(org.apache.camel.CamelAuthorizationException.class).handled(true).transform(simple("Access Denied with the Policy of ${exception.policyId} !")).setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, simple("401"));`

Comment: I have already implemented a solution using option 2 but forgot to update this question. I also use JWT with this and it is working very well now. I will post an example of how it looks tomorrow.

Comment: @P3anuts--would love the see your alternate solution.

Comment: See separate answer I posted. If you need more info, just let me know and I will add it. Was a bit stressed when I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://camel.apache.org/jetty.html

Jetty handlers and security configuration

You can configure a list of Jetty handlers on the endpoint, which can be useful for enabling advanced Jetty security features. These handlers are configured in Spring XML as follows:

```
<-- Jetty Security handling -->
<bean id="userRealm" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASUserRealm">
    <property name="name" value="tracker-users"/>
    <property name="loginModuleName" value="ldaploginmodule"/>
</bean>

<bean id="constraint" class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC"/>
    <property name="roles" value="tracker-users"/>
    <property name="authenticate" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="constraintMapping" class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="constraint"/>
    <property name="pathSpec" value="/*"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler">
    <property name="userRealm" ref="userRealm"/>
    <property name="constraintMappings" ref="constraintMapping"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at that page and also the page for Spring Security which is what I would like to use. I am just having a hard time to understand how the play together. 
For example, do I need to configure Jetty Security if I want to use Spring Security? I will update my original question with my current configuration.